# Reading geospatial properties of ArcGIS web services using C#?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcobjects, c#

I need to display the Geospatial properties of ArcGIS web-services (like service name, service type, description, copyright, etc.) which are available in the "ArcGIS Services Directory", in my C# application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you don't have any in memory reference to the Map, then use the ESRI REST API. it's easy enough in c# to setup a call to a url, and parse through the result JSON.

for example this url:
http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Specialty/ESRI_StateCityHighway_USA/MapServer

here's the help:
http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/SDK/REST/index.html?mapserver.html